# assigning different click handlers to a global control template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using a slightly modified version of this SimpleExpander so that my expander headers are clickable.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/248112/Templating-WPF-Expander-Control

Here is the relevant source code:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SimpleExpanderTemp" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">

            <DockPanel>

                <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="ExpanderButton" />

                    <!-- button with hard coded click handler -->
                    <Button Name="SharerHeader" Click="SharerHeader_Click_1"> 
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" />
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>

            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Works great.  Now I want to reuse this control template across my application, so I moved the code into my app.xaml.  However, my header is hardcoded to a click event, and I want to be able to set the click handler based on the page the expander is being used in.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Just don't assign the click handler in XAML, set it in the code behind...

Comment: How do I access the button in code behind?

Comment: Got it.  Involved using Expander.Template.FindName after having called Expander.ApplyTemplate().  Thanks servy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a new ResourceDictionary to your project (name it RD1.xaml), move your Template into it.
2. Add a new Class (name it RD1.xaml.cs) with this signature

   ```
   public partial class SomeClassName : ResourceDictionary
   ```
3. Add this line of code to the ResourceDictionary tag (in RD1.xaml)

   ```
   x:Class="WpfApplication1.SomeClassName"
   ```
4. Add these lines of code to App.xaml (add FolderName if RD1 is in a folder)

   ```
   <Application.Resources>
           <ResourceDictionary>
               <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                   <ResourceDictionary Source="FolderName\RD1.xaml"/>
               </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
           </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
   ```
5. Now you can have your event handler implementation in RD1.xaml.cs

Comment: but i don't want to put an event handler in RD1.xaml.cs.  I want to put my event handlers on the .cs pages where my template is being used.  With your example I am limited to one click handler.

Comment: when you use your template on different data, your data has something that can help the event handler distinguish between the source data. like type, an enum, tag or parent or something like that. from the event handler you can cast the sender to a base class like: if((sender as Person).PersonType == PersonTypes.Admin)... or if(sender is Admin) (sender as Admin).SomeFunction();

Comment: I took your advice.  This seems to be the easiest solution.  Thanks much.