# access control within data template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Relevant: previous question
[assigning different click handlers to a global control template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071442/assigning-different-click-handlers-to-a-global-control-template#comment17756609_13071442)

I have the following xaml:

```
<Expander Name="SharesExpander" Template="{StaticResource SimpleExpanderTemp}" Header="Shares">
    <ItemsControl Name="SharesControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Sharers}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Name="ShareExpander" Template="{StaticResource SimpleExpanderTemp}" Header="{Binding Name}">
                    <local:FileTypesListBoxControl Margin="25,-10,-10,-10" BorderThickness="10" />
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Expander>
```

I am trying to access the header button of the inner expander via code behind to add a click handler.

I can retrieve the button for the outer expander using `SharesExpander.Template.FindName("ExpanderHeader", SharesExpander)`, but I can't figure out how to get at the inner expander within the data template.  I have tried traversing the `VisualTree` and `LogicalTree`, but I always seem to end up back at the outer expander.  I can retrieve the outer expanders data template, and I can call `FindName` on that, but can't figure out what element to use as the second parameter.  Help!

One attempt:

```
foreach (var item in SharesControl.Items)
{
    //test is always null
    var test = SharesControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
}
```

Another attempt:

```
ControlTemplate controlTemplate = SharesControl.Template;
var control = controlTemplate.FindName("ShareExpander", ?whatGoesHere);
```

yet again:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    //test again always null
    var test = ContactSharesItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as Expander;
}
```

Comment: The inner Expander has a name - `ShareExpander`. Can you not reference that directly?

Comment: No. From my understanding, controls within a data template are not directly accessible

Comment: I always think of templates like Cookie Cutters. You can't find the cookie just from looking at the cookie cutter, but you can use them to make actual cookies that you can find (and eat) :) But anyways, what do you need from the actual inner Expander? You could use the `ItemContainerGenerator` to find the UI item that was generated from the DataTemplate, but if you can wire your application up differently so you don't need to do that, that would be better

Comment: I need the inner expander so I can add click handlers. My attempts so far at using the `ItemContainerGenerator` have failed miserably.

Comment: So far the only thing I have been able to retrieve is the view models associated with the controls the itemsControl is generating.  I have been completely unable to get a reference to the actual controls themselves